# Exibindo um branch diferente do Master no repositorio

Tags: git

Boa tarde a todos

temos um servidor próprio e versionamos com git.

A equipe de testes precisa testar um branch diferente do master, e eles não tem o git instalado nos seus locais, preciso que o site exiba esse outro branch e, após os testes, eu possa voltar ao master...

seria algo como ***git checkout origin outro-branch***

desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda

Comment: Faz um merge da master com a branch e depois faz um rollback

Comment: Não seria o caso de vocês liberarem um release com o branch desejado em um ambiente que o time de QA tenha acesso? Outro ponto, é muito importante que o "time de testes" tenha disponível as mesmas ferramentas que os desenvolvedores, eles realmente fazem parte do dev team e têm a mesma responsabilidade e importância na entrega de uma feature.